# validating whether measurements are complete, double or have missing rows in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset  which consists of measurements over multiple timepoints for multiple individuals. However, for some of the individuals I have one or two measurements and some even four (standard is 3). See the example data:

[data layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKDzM.png)

From this example table I would only need the measurements from ID 1 and 2, ID 3 has 3 measurements but timepoint two is measured twice. ID 4 and 5 have missing timepoints.

Is there a way to  check in a dataframe wheter for each ID the measurements are complete?

I have written some code for this:

```
  get.completeTimepoints <- function(dataFrame){
  unique.ids <- matrix(unique(dataFrame$id))
  n.ids <- nrow(unique.ids)
  for (i in 1:n.ids) {
  
    temp.vector <- filter(dataFrame, id == unique.ids[i,]) #selects the id and all its measurements
  
   validate.timepoints(temp.vector) #call validate function

  }
}
```

I am currently stuck on how to check if measurements for all three timepoints are present(see function below). Any help would be appreciated

```
validate.timepoints <- function(dataFrame){
  row.df <- nrow(dataFrame)
   
  if(row.df ==3){
    #check if all 3 timepoints are present in the dataframe
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Images are not helpful. Also show expected output for the data shared. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure about the complexities of your data frame, but for the given data layout, I'm assuming you want a function, when the id is given, returns True if time points are exactly 1, 2 and 3.

If that's the case, following should work:

```
t = data.frame(ID = c(rep(1,3), rep(2,3), rep(3,3), rep(4,2), rep(5,1)),
               tp = c(seq(1,3), seq(1,3), 1,2,2,1,2,1), 
               v1 = rnorm(12,0,1), v2 = rnorm(12,0,1), v3 = rnorm(12,0,1))


ids = seq(1,5)
validate.timepoints = function(df, id){
  return(seq(1,3) %in% t$tp[which(t$ID == id)])
}
check = sapply(ids, function(x) all(validate.timepoints(t, x)))
```

Which returns:

```
> check
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```